# insert column in multiheader dataframe using loc

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, insert, stack

I am trying to insert column in a multi header data frame which is the output of pandas pivot. I have used pandas. loc option for this, but I am not able to insert a column at a specific location.

Here is my code:

```
data = {'Commander': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'],
        'Date': ['2012, 02, 08', '2012, 02, 08', '2012, 02, 08',
                 '2012, 02, 08', '2012, 02, 08'],
        'Hour':['00','01','02','03','04'],
        'Subject': ['Maths','Science','Biology','Chemistry','Physics'],
        'Score': [4, 24, 31, 3, 1],
       'Grade':[1,2,1,4,5],
       'credit':[20,50,40,20,10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1=pd.pivot_table(df,index=['Commander','Hour'],columns=['Date'],values=['Score','Grade','credit'],aggfunc=np.max)
```

I am trying to insert another subcolumn for grade.for which I tried below code, which allows me to insert column but it inserted column in the last, not under grade. Can anyone please guide how to achieve this.

```
df1.loc[:,('Grade','subcredit')]=df1.loc[:,('Grade','2012, 02, 08')]*5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`insert` the column exactly where you want it. This is useful if `sort` has the possibility of re-ordering other columns you don't want to change.

Find the last column that belongs to 'Grade' checking `argmax` on the reversed array. We'll insert right after this.

```
i = int(len(df1.columns) - (df1.columns.get_level_values(0) == 'Grade')[::-1].argmax())
df1.insert(i, ('Grade', 'subcredit'), df1.loc[:,('Grade','2012, 02, 08')]*5)
```

---

```
                      Grade                  Score       credit
Date           2012, 02, 08 subcredit 2012, 02, 08 2012, 02, 08
Commander Hour                                                 
Amy       04              5        25            1           10
Jake      03              4        20            3           20
Jason     00              1         5            4           20
Molly     01              2        10           24           50
Tina      02              1         5           31           40
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add one more line of code, to sort the index (the parameter `axis=1` sorts the column index):

```
df1.sort_index(axis=1)

                      Grade                  Score       credit
Date           2012, 02, 08 subcredit 2012, 02, 08 2012, 02, 08
Commander Hour                                                 
Amy       04              5        25            1           10
Jake      03              4        20            3           20
Jason     00              1         5            4           20
Molly     01              2        10           24           50
Tina      02              1         5           31           40
```